# When I attempt to add a specific character of a string through push_back() it throws me a type conversion error

Tags: c++, vector, type-conversion

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input);
    int x = input.length();
    vector<string> arr;
    for(x; x==0; x-2){
        arr.push_back(input[x]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error when I try to compile:

> simplearraysum.cpp:16:23: error: reference to type 'const std::__vector_base<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::value_type' (aka 'const std::string') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'std::basic_string<char>::value_type' (aka 'char')
>
> arr.push_back(input[x]);

Could anyone offer some advice on what I could do?

Comment: Is the goal to add a single-character string, to the vector of strings `arr` ? Fixing the error is easy, (change `arr` to be `vector<char>` but that's pure guesswork since we don't know what the *intention* of this code is.

Comment: yes that was the intention and it works now thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several bugs in the code that make it fail; most important the third part of the for loop: `x-2` calculates the result of the subtraction, and then moves on. It is never stored anywhere, so x never changes. The loop runs forever, inserting over and over `input[x]` into the vector, until something blows up. You probably mean to use: `x = x-2`.

Second problem is if x is odd - subtracting 2 will never hit exactly zero, so the loop will again never stop. You should use `x>=0` or such for the condition.

Third, `input[x]` is a char, not a string; the vector expects strings. That is what the shown error message talks about.

Fourth, if x is the length of the string, `input[x]` accesses the char behind the string - in C and C++, indices start with 0, so an array of x chars goes from arr[0] to arr[x-1].

Comment: The first problem that you mentioned, as far as I am aware is invalid, since it is the counter modification in a for loop is actually does change the value of x. I do agree, however that the second problem is valid however your provided solution makes it so that the for loop never runs in the first place. Something such as x==0 || x==1 would be more apt for the condition.

Also my original problem of not being able to push input[x] into the vector<string> was not really addressed.

Comment: @DarklySpaced `x-2` doesn't do a darn thing to the value of `x`, so your assumption of "it is the counter modification in a for loop is actually does change the value of x." is wrong. Turn up your warnings.

Comment: It is addressed, under 'third': you are trying to push a _char_ into a vector of _strings_. A vector of _strings_ takes strings, not chars. Use a vector of chars to push a char.

Comment: @DarklySpaced ... but if you really want to create strings from the `char`s, then you could do: `for (auto x = input.length(); x--;) { arr.emplace_back(1, input[x]); }`